# How to use Dagger in non-Android Gradle Java application?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, gradle, dagger

Dagger is advertised as "A fast dependency injector for Android and Java". But I'm not able to make it run without Gradle 'android' plugin.

```
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.1'
```

There is no `provided` in 'java' or 'application' gradle plugin I'm using. It is even mentioned in [this bug report](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-784).

Making it both 'compile' yelds no result. The same `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class ... could not be loaded.` is thrown.

How gradle with 'java' and 'application' can be configured to use dagger annotation processor?

Comment: Works just fine for me with these two `compile` dependencies and the `java` and `application` plugins. Adapter classes are generated automatically by the annotation processor, without any further configuration. Tested with Gradle 2.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work fine with both defined as `compile`. The error indicates other problem with your code.

If you still want to use provided scope please read this: http://www.sinking.in/blog/provided-scope-in-gradle/

Quick example how to use provided:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

dependencies {
    provided 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
}
```

Comment: You are righ. The issue was that I was using Intellij IDEA default "run" that is NOT calling gradle 'build' so nothing got generated.